# Is it possible in bash to finish command piped through gzip gracefully?

Tags: bash, gzip

I have startup script which calls command that produces a lot of output. To preserve space I gzipped its output:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_command 2>&1 | tee >(gzip --stdout > "1.log.gz")
```

Sadly, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, `gzip` stops abruptly and compressed log gets damaged. Is there a way to finish command gracefully to get valid gz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce your problem, using "yes" as a substitute for your program -- that is

```
yes 2>&1 | tee >(gzip --stdout > "1.log.gz")
```

created perfectly valid gz file every time, so wondering if there is something else going on.

However you can isolate the two parts of the command by using named pipes, like this;

```
# create a named pipe
mknod mypipe p 

# start a background job that reads from the pipe
gzip --stdout > "1.log.gz" <mypipe &  

# now do work -- ctrl-c only affect this process
my_command 2>&1 | tee mypipe
```

Comment: Indeed, I can't reproduce the problem with `yes` either. Maybe it's because this command should set signals? If you replace `yes` with shell script which prints 'y' in cycle, the issue is reproduced. Nevertheless, trick with FIFO pipe helps, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you can't break it safely because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will kill `STDOUT` and compressing can't be finished successfully.
If `STDOUT` don't matter try to use

`my_command &>/dev/null | tee >(gzip > "1.log.gz")`

Comment: If you redirect both STDOUT and STDERR to /dev/null, what would tee read? And STDOUT does matter, I just want to compress it on the fly.